# How to connect java using eclipse with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I got the error

> Error:java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Malay
>   Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one
>   time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via
>   the server timezone configuration property) to use a more specific
>   time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried changing my computer's time with our local timezone but still the same error.

I tried adding my connection:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliatnTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false","root",""
```

still no work and i got the error:

> Error:java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load
>   connection class because of underlying exception:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database
>   URL, failed to parse the connection string near
>   ';useJDBCCompliatnTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

My connection string is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raqs","root","");
```

Comment: Is an instance of MySQL actually running when you try this?  Did you configure it to listen on local host and on port 3306?  Can you show us how you configured MySQL networking so we can verify that it's running correctly?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I have tried connecting MySQL database with a php code and I can access the database in my local host

Comment: Im using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2

Comment: Im using mysql-connector-java-8.0.12 for connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your typo. It's 'compliant', not 'compliatn'. Just like the error says.

Comment: Fixed it but still an error: Error:java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Malay Peninsula Standard Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem:

I have only added `serverTimezone=UTC` to my URL. And to be very careful in declaring a query which is case sensitive. And make sure in declaring variables in String or in Int and etc.

My codes worked well already and successfully connected my database to the eclipse ^_^